# How do you set an enum property on a GLib object?

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glib, gobject, pango

I am trying to set the "ellipsize" enum property on a [GtkCellRendererText](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererText.html#gtk-cell-renderer-text-new) object.

I am trying to use `g_object_set_property` as follows:

```
GtkCellRenderer *renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();

GValue val = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init (&val, G_TYPE_ENUM);
g_value_set_enum (&val, PANGO_ELLIPSIZE_END);
g_object_set_property (G_OBJECT(renderer), "ellipsize", &val);
```

However, I get an error message at run time:

```
(infog:27114): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 12:24:29.848: ../../../../gobject/gvalue.c:188: cannot initialize GValue with type 'GEnum', this type is abstract with regards to GValue use, use a more specific (derived) type
```

How do I get the type ID for [`enum PangoEllipsizeMode`](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/pango-Layout-Objects.html#PangoEllipsizeMode) that derives from `G_TYPE_ENUM`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialise the `GValue` container with the type of the enumeration that the property expects. `G_TYPE_ENUM` is the generic, abstract enumeration type.

The "ellipsize" property of `GtkCellRendererText` expects a `PangoEllipsizeMode` enumeration value, which has a GType of `PANGO_TYPE_ELLIPSIZE_MODE`.

```cpp
GtkCellRenderer *renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();

GValue val = G_VALUE_INIT;

g_value_init (&val, PANGO_TYPE_ELLIPSIZE_MODE);
g_value_set_enum (&val, PANGO_ELLIPSIZE_END);

g_object_set_property (G_OBJECT(renderer), "ellipsize", &val);

// Always unset your value to release any memory that may be associated with it
g_value_unset (&val);
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I had missed this definition in the documentation I looked at.

Answer (score 4):

Using `g_object_set` instead works:

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT(renderer), "ellipsize", PANGO_ELLIPSIZE_END, NULL);
```